# Simple webpage fade out effect using CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css, optimization, fade

I have a very simple method below using CSS that fades in a webpage when the visitor arrives at the site. However, when the visitor leaves to another site, the page disappears abruptly instead of a smooth fade out before leaving.

> **Question:**
>
> How can I modify the code below using only CSS to achieve a simple
>   fade out effect when the visitor leaves the page?

**CSS:**

```
@keyframes fade { 
     0% {opacity: 0;} 
     100% {opacity: 1;} 
}
@-webkit-keyframes fade { 
     0% {opacity: 0;} 
     100% {opacity: 1;} 
}
@-moz-keyframes fade { 
     0% {opacity: 0;} 
     100% {opacity: 1;} 
}
@-o-keyframes fade { 
     0% {opacity: 0;} 
     100% {opacity: 1;} 
}

html {
    opacity: 0;
    animation: fade 3s ease-in-out 1.5s forwards;
    -webkit-animation: fade 3s ease-in-out 1.5s forwards;
    -moz-animation: fade 3s ease-in-out 1.5s forwards;
    -o-animation: fade 3s ease-in-out 1.5s forwards;
}
```

Comment: you can't with just CSS. you might be able to using the [onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) event using javascript

Comment: i dont think you can do this just using css you'll probably need to use javascript

Comment: If you leave to another URL, the browser immediately loads the content of the next URL and swaps the page contents. This means, that the current page is not executed anymore (the CSS animation abrupt). You would need to delay the link execution to show the complete animation before leaving. You could write a delaying link execution function in JavaScript (prevent default behavior of link and use `location.href` to redirect to the actual page by reading the `href` attribute of the clicked link after 1.5s [with `setTimeout`])..

Comment: Thanks, everyone. These answers make sense. I was hoping CSS had the magic for this one.